# Load HtmlDocument from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a stream that is being used by multiple `HtmlDocument` types, but `Stream.CanSeek` is false so once I read the stream the first time I'm unable to pass that same stream to another `HtmlDocument` object to load it.

I was thinking I could copy the stream to a `MemoryStream` and then pass the memory stream to each `HtmlDcoument` but when I call `document.Load(memoryStream)` the `document.DocumentNode` is null.

What gives?

```
private HtmlNode getNode(MemoryStream stream) {
    var document = new HtmlDocument();
    document.Load(stream);
    return document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html/head");
}
```

Comment: The answer provided should be the way to go, but my guess for your question is that you need to set the position of the stream to `0` everytime you need to load from it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why loading same data several times? Load your html once into document and then use same document instance for parsing all required data.

Make your methods accept document:

```
private HtmlNode getNode(HtmlDocument document) 
{
    return document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html/head");
}
```

And then pass single document instance everywhere

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.Load(stream);
var node1 = getNode(document);
var node2 = getOtherNode(document);
```

Or even consider creating class where document will be class field. Thus you will not need to pass it to each method.